# Progress bar between activities Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I know there are other threads talking about this, but they didn't help in my case. I have a list of buttons and each leads to a different mapActivity. For now, I've been inspired by the code made by Android Studio for LoginActivity which also has a ProgressBar. The list of buttons disappears and the progressBar starts to show, but then stops because HomeActivity.onPause is launched and the onCreate of myMap activity is also launch but the app is frozen on the blocked progressBar. About a moment, my map activity is visible. How can I make the progress bar spin during this?

```
package com.example.florian.myapplication.Activities;
 
import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
 
import com.example.florian.myapplication.Activities.MapsActivities.MainActivity;
import com.example.florian.myapplication.Activities.MapsActivities.MainActivityRec;
import com.example.florian.myapplication.Activities.MapsActivities.MainActivityRel;
import com.example.florian.myapplication.R;
 
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 
    private ChangeActivityTask changeTask;
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
 
        Button obsPonctButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.obs_ponc_button);
        obsPonctButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showProgress(true);
                changeTask = new ChangeActivityTask(false);
                changeTask.execute((Void) null);
            }
        });
 
        Button protocoleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.protocole_button);
        protocoleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showProgress(true);
                changeTask = new ChangeActivityTask(false);
                changeTask.execute((Void) null);
            }
        });
 
        Button releveBouton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.relevé_button);
        releveBouton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showProgress(true);
                changeTask = new ChangeActivityTask(false);
                changeTask.execute((Void) null);
            }
        });
 
        Button syncButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sync_button);
        syncButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                synchroniserMission();
            }
        });
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        showProgress(false);
    }
 
    public Intent generateIntent (boolean isReleveActivity){
        Intent intent;
        if(isReleveActivity)
            intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,MainActivityRel.class);
        else
            intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,MainActivityRec.class);
        return intent;
    }
 
    /**
     * Shows the progress UI and hides the login form.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
    private void showProgress(final boolean show) {
        // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
        // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
        // the progress spinner.
        final LinearLayout buttonList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttonList);
        final ProgressBar mProgressView = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.action_progress);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
            int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
 
            buttonList.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            buttonList.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                    show ? 0 : 1).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    buttonList.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
 
            mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            mProgressView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                    show ? 1 : 0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                }
            });
        } else {
            // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
            // and hide the relevant UI components.
            mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            buttonList.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.w("Bienvenue", "dans le onpause");
    }
 
    private void synchroniserMission(){
 
    }
    public class ChangeActivityTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
 
        private final boolean isReleveActivity;
 
        private Intent intent;
 
        ChangeActivityTask(boolean isReleveActivity) {
            this.isReleveActivity = isReleveActivity;
        }
 
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.
            intent = generateIntent(isReleveActivity);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
 
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            showProgress(false);
        }
 
        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            showProgress(false);
        }
 
 
    }
}
```

I hope I'm being clear and you can help me through this.

Comment: Have a look at [animate between activities](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/overview.html#animate_between_activities)

Comment: So you're sugesting to do [this](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity.html#start-with-element) and the shared element would be the progress bar ?